# My code giving me error " 'JpegImageFile' object is not subscriptable " when I am trying ro extract their text and filling it into a text file

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tesseract, python-tesseract

```py
from tkinter import filedialog
import pytesseract as tess
tess.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as tess
files = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
n = len(files)
text = [n]
print(len(text))
for i in range(0,n):
    img = Image.open(files[i])
    img[i].show()
    text[i] = tess.image_to_string(img[i])
    file = open(f'text{i}.txt',"w+")
    file[i].write(text[i])
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What data type should each object be? Is `img` a `list` or a `PIL.Image`? What is `file`? Is it a built in file hander or is it a `list`?

Comment: @TheLizzard Aren't all those questions answered in the code itself? `img` is indeed an `Image` object, `file` is a file handler, which the OP tries to index.

Comment: @CoolCloud I am trying to get OP to find their own mistake/s. For example I have no idea if OP wants to keep a list of all of the files or not.

Comment: @TheLizzard Oh, that makes sense. My bad.

Comment: @CoolCloud I am experimenting with a new strategy, getting OP to realise their own mistakes. But it doesn't work when OP doesn't respond :D.

Comment: @TheLizzard Nice, but its going to get tiring and time consuming after a while, I've seen people do it. Better is to just provide an answer and forget these.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get the "i-th" value of an image, which is not possible.

```
img[i].show()
    ^
```

It should probably be:

```
img.show()
```

You also have some other issues with indexing:

1. To create a list of size n you can use `text = [None] * len`. An even easier way would be to append a new item in the list: `text = []` and then `text.append(tess.image_to_string(img))`
2. The file object is also no subscriptable:

```
file[i].write(text[i])
     ^
```

It would be just `file.write(text[i])`

3. Lastly, don't forget to close the file at the end, because otherwise you won't be able to access it: `file.close()`.

Comment: That isn't the only problem with the code. When writing an answer for a question make sure that you fix all of OP's mistakes.

Comment: I edited to include all the possible errors/problems that I found. Hope that helps you

Comment: Also mention that the OP is importing one library twice

Answer (score 0):

## Thanks to all the commentators!!!

The answer is:

```py
from tkinter import filedialog
import pytesseract as tess
tess.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as tess
files=filedialog.askopenfilenames()
n=len(files)
text=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    img = Image.open(files[i])
    text.append(tess.image_to_string(img))
    file=open(f'text{i}.txt',"w+")
    file.write(text[i])
```